# ¿cómo variar el nombre de un objeto/tabla de acuerdo a un vector c de FOR en R?

Tags: r, bucle-for

requiero construir una tabla a nivel nacional, urbano, rural y otras desagregaciones para las mismas categorias (básico, limitado, no mejorado, al aire libre). El codigo genera la tabla pero la sobreescribe obtengo la tabla a nivel rural.

```
Desagregaciones <- c("Nacional", "Urbano", "Rural") 

for (x in Desagregaciones) {
x_problema <- bdd %>% 
     filter(!is.na(i_sanea) & !!sym(x)==1) %>% 
     group_by(i_sanea) %>% 
     summarise(survey_mean(na.rm = TRUE , vartype = c("se", "ci", "var", "cv"))*100) %>% 
     mutate(i_sanea=case_when(i_sanea==1 ~ "Básico",
                             i_sanea==2 ~ "Limitado",
                             i_sanea==3 ~ "No mejorado",
                             i_sanea==4 ~ "Al aire libre"))
}
```

**x_problema** debe cambiar de acuerdo los valores de x ("Nacional", "Urbano", "Rural").

¿Me podrian ayudar con algun metodo para que el nombre del objeto pueda variar de acuerdo a los valores que toma x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando tu respuesta, si quieres desagregar el consolidado utiliza `group_split`:

```
Desagregaciones_saneamiento %>%
  map_dfr(
    ~cbind(.x, bdd %>% filter(!is.na(i_sanea) & !!sym(.x)==1) %>% 
             group_by(i_sanea) %>%
             summarise(survey_mean(na.rm = TRUE , vartype = c("se", "ci", "var", "cv"))*100) %>% 
             mutate(i_sanea=case_when(i_sanea==1 ~ "Básico",
                                      i_sanea==2 ~ "Limitado",
                                      i_sanea==3 ~ "No mejorado",
                                      i_sanea==4 ~ "Al aire libre")) %>% 
             ungroup())) %>% 
  group_by(i_sanea) %>% 
  group_split()
```

Answer (score 0):

No pude generar varias tablas pero pude generar una tabla consolidada con las variables que requeria:

```
Desagregaciones_saneamiento <- c("Nacional", "Urbano", "Rural", "Pobreza", "Extrema_pobreza")

Tabulado <- Desagregaciones_saneamiento %>%
  map_dfr(
    ~cbind(.x, bdd %>% filter(!is.na(i_sanea) & !!sym(.x)==1) %>% 
             group_by(i_sanea) %>%
             summarise(survey_mean(na.rm = TRUE , vartype = c("se", "ci", "var", "cv"))*100) %>% 
             mutate(i_sanea=case_when(i_sanea==1 ~ "Básico",
                                      i_sanea==2 ~ "Limitado",
                                      i_sanea==3 ~ "No mejorado",
                                      i_sanea==4 ~ "Al aire libre"))))
```

Comment: No te respondas a ti mismo para agregar información, edita tu pregunta